# How can I avoid a delay with continues touch detection in swift?

Tags: ios, touch, control, swift

I want control a character on my screen with a continuous swipe gesture. As soon as I do a swipe `+x` or `-x` my character moves left or right. And as long as I hold my finger it continuous to move to the direction in that I swiped. When I swipe into the opposite direction of my last swipe without leaving my finger from the touch ground, my character should move into this direction. When I release my finger from the touch screen, my character should stops instantly.

**My problem is that there is often a small delay within the change of direction. And this delay makes it less precise.**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    var player = self.childNodeWithName("man")

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        lastFingerPosition = location

    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent){
    var player = self.childNodeWithName("man")

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        if(location.x > lastFingerPosition?.x && lastMoveDirection != "right"){
            movePlayer("right")
        } else if(location.x < lastFingerPosition?.x && lastMoveDirection != "left"){
            movePlayer("left")
        }
    }
}

//@Todo: Wenn man touchMoved und nicht über dem Button hoch geht, wird die Action nicht aufgehoben
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var player = self.childNodeWithName("man")

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(location)

        player?.removeAllActions()
        lastMoveDirection = ""
    }
}

func movePlayer(direction: String) {
    var player = self.childNodeWithName("man")

    if(lastMoveDirection != direction){
        player?.removeAllActions()
        lastMoveDirection = direction

        var duration:CGFloat? = 0
        var x = player?.position.x
        duration = x!

        if(direction == "left"){
            var xDestination:CGFloat = 10
            var run = SKAction.moveToX(10, duration: NSTimeInterval(Double(duration! / runSpeed)))
            player?.runAction(run, withKey: "moveLeft")
        } else if(direction == "right") {
            duration = self.frame.width - x!
            var xDestination = frame.size.width - 1
            var run = SKAction.moveToX(xDestination, duration: NSTimeInterval(Double(duration! / runSpeed)))
            player?.runAction(run, withKey: "moveRight")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a programmatic problem. It is more an issue of the control itself. Because a `swipe` with your finger into one direction and then, a swipe to the opposite direction results in a rotation of your thumb.

And while it's rotating a little bit, it is not moving and that causes the feeling of a delay.

I guess this control is useless, if you need really precise moves - just because of the anatomy of our thumbs.